# Ошибка с DISTINCT для CLOB колонки: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

При указании ключевого слова `DISTINCT` для `CLOB` колонки в запросе получаю ошибку:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

Запрос такого вида:

```
select distinct myclobcolumn, type from table
```

Пробовал использовать `to_char()`, но все равно получаю ошибку, так как размер буфера для `VARCHAR2` меньше, чем фактический размер `CLOB`.

Comment: Здесь есть несколько вариантов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921982/select-distinct-clob-column-from-table

Comment: А что вы хотите этим добится? Похоже на [проблему XY (молотка)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709). Обычно lob данные сравниваются на основании других колонок.

Answer (score 3):

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) явно сказано, что `DISTINCT` не допускает `LOB` колонок:

> You cannot specify DISTINCT if the select_list contains LOB columns.

Желаемый результат можно получить таким запросом:

```
create table docs (id int primary key, doc clob)
/
insert into docs 
    select rownum, trim (column_value) 
    from xmlTable ('"content1","content1","content2"')
/
select * from docs d1
where not exists (
    select * from docs d2
    where dbms_lob.compare (d1.doc, d2.doc) = 0
    and d1.rowid > d2.rowid)
/

        ID DOC                                                                             
---------- ---------------------------------------
         1 content1                               
         3 content2
```

---

PS: Но побайтное/посимвольное сравнение `LOB` значений довольно редкая операция. Обычно `LOB` однозначно идентифицируются другими колонками, например: контрольная сумма, длина, дата последнего изменения, источник итд.